# How do I compare 2 columns and return a third based off the result?

Tags: sql

List the employee names and alongside their supervisor names

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
   EmployeeID char(4) PRIMARY KEY,
   EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   HourlyRate real,
   SkillType varchar(20),
   SupervisorID char(4) NOT NULL
)
```

So I want to return a table showing

```
Employee Name || Supervisor Name
```

I have tried

```
Select 
    EmployeeName, 
    (Select EmployeeName Where SupervisorID = EmployeeID) As Supervisor 
From Employees
```

but it only shows values where the `Employee` is their own supervisor, for the others it returns null. I must be missing something simple, but I cannot figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the same table again

```
Select e.EmployeeName, s.EmployeeName As Supervisor 
From Employees e
left join Employees s on s.employeeID = e.supervisorID
```

Comment: Cheers, hadn't covered joins in lectures yet, but from what I read this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EMAIN.EmployeeName AS Employee,
      (SELECT E.EmployeeName FROM Employees AS E WHERE EMAIN.EmployeeID = E.SupervisorID) AS Supervisor
FROM Employees AS EMAIN
```